# How set the array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have got this Array

```
Array ( [0] => 9314802498 [1] => 9314801890 [2] => MOSWAPELE ESTHER [3] => BENNETH )
```

I Want to retrieve like that Array

```
Array ( [0] => 9314802498 [1] => MOSWAPELE ESTHER [2] => 9314801890  [3] => BENNETH )
```

Comment: seems like you may have answered your own question.  if not, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Please describe the transformation in an abstract manner, otherwise my answer would be: Swap the second and third element ;)

Comment: `$myArray = array_merge(array_filter($myArray, function($key) {return $key % 2 == 0; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY), array_filter($myArray, function($key) {return $key % 2 == 1; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));`.... requires PHP >= 5.6.0

Comment: $arr = array( 
0 => 9314802498,
1 => 9314801890, 
2 => 'MOSWAPELE ESTHER',
3 => 'BENNETH' 
);
$temp_val = $arr[1];
$arr[1] = $arr[2];
$arr[2] = $temp_val;
print_r($arr);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help -

```
$array = array ( 0 => 9314802498, 1 => 9314801890, 2 => 'MOSWAPELE ESTHER', 3 => 'BENNETH' );

$temp= array_chunk($array, count($array)/2);

$final = array();

foreach($temp[0] as $key => $val) {
   $final[]= $val;
   $final[]= !empty($temp[1][$key]) ? $temp[1][$key] : null;
}

var_dump($final);
```

**Output**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  float(9314802498)
  [1]=>
  string(16) "MOSWAPELE ESTHER"
  [2]=>
  float(9314801890)
  [3]=>
  string(7) "BENNETH"
}
```

*Assuming the count of numbers and names would be equal in that array.* If not -

```
$temp= array_chunk($array, ceil(count($array)/2));
```

Answer (score 0):

change the key

```
$arr = Array ( [0] => 9314802498 [1] => 9314801890 [2] => MOSWAPELE ESTHER [3] => BENNETH );

$arr[1] = 'MOSWAPELE ESTHER';
$arr[2] = '9314801890';
```

It will give  you desired answer

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the key values like this:

```
$arr1 = array('9314802498', '9314801890', 'MOSWAPELE ESTHER', 'BENNETH');
$temp = $arr1[1];
$arr1[1] = $arr1[2];
$arr1[2] = $temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$arr = array( 
0 => 9314802498,
1 => 9314801890, 
2 => 'MOSWAPELE ESTHER',
3 => 'BENNETH' 
);
$temp_val = $arr[1];
$arr[1] = $arr[2];
$arr[2] = $temp_val;
print_r($arr);
```

Output

```
Array ( [0] => 9314802498 [1] => MOSWAPELE ESTHER [2] => 9314801890 [3] => BENNETH )
```